# Random Number Generator - Display 1 instead of Zero

Tags: swift, xcode6.4

In Xcode 7 & swift I have a label which generates a random number between 0 - 50, however when it generates a zero I want it to display number 1 instead.
what code do I need to add to do this?

label1TextLabel.text = String(arc4random_uniform(51))

Regards.

Del

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Write this code:

```
var number = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(51))

if number == 0 {
   number = 1
}

label1TextLabel.text = "\(number)"
```

Comment: Many thanks Eric. Works just fine. Del

Comment: Even though this code works it will will produce 1 for either 1 or 0.